# If all bond angles in AX₃ are the same, then which of the following are correct conclusions about AX₃?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure, hybridization

#### Question

> If all bond angles in $\ce{AX3}$ are the same, then which of the following are correct conclusions about $\ce{AX3}?$
>
> (**A**) $\ce{AX3}$ must be polar.
> (**B**) $\ce{AX3}$ must be planar.
> (**C**) $\ce{AX3}$ must have at least 5 valence electrons.
> (**D**) $\ce{X}$ must be connected to the central atom via single or double bonds.

#### My Attempt

This is clearly a case of $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridisation. So, I thought about molecules like $\ce{BF3}$. As the bond angle needs to be same, it must not be polar. $\mathrm{sp^2}$ has trigonal planar structure, so (**B**) must be correct.

But my book says that the answer is (**D**) only (this question was of single correct choice type).

Why are (**B**) and (**C**) not the answers and why is (**D**) the answer?

Comment: Bond angles in $\ce{NH3}$ are equal, but the molecular structure is not planar. That's a good place to start.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Yes I see that rules out (B). But what do we mean by the option (C)? What does it mean when it says that the valence electrons of AX$_3$ is 5? Is it referring to the central atom or the whole molecule's number of valence electrons?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Also, isn't NH$_3$ polar??

Comment: Yes, it is polar. As for option (C) - it's unclear to me and I think it's poorly-worded - all you need to do to disprove it is come up with one example of a molecule that has neither 5 valence electrons on the central atom or in the whole molecule. Maybe $\ce{BH3}$?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Boron having 3 valence electrons and 3 electrons, 1 for each in hydrogen would make the molecule have 6 valence electrons wouldn't it?

Comment: Correct. And there you have disproved option (C), which leaves you with (D). This approach to problem-solving - find a counterexample to inform you yes/no - is generally useful for multiple choice questions such as this.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt But how would that be disproving option (C)? I simply got that there are 6 valence electrons in the particular molecule of BH$_3$. How do I know that there isn't some molecule with 5 valence electrons possible? Because it says "at least".

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong. Anyway, find a counterexample and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

(A) and (B) are answered well in the comments by [Todd Minehardt](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/865/todd-minehardt) and [Techie5879](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/83776/techie5879). So, I'll summarise their points and clarify (C) to justify the answer (D).

(A) $\ce{AX3}$ must be polar.

Consider the case of $\ce{BH3}$ to disprove statement (A), since it is a non polar molecule with a trigonal planar structure (equal bond angles).

(B) $\ce{AX3}$ must be planar.

Consider the case of $\ce{NH3}$ to disprove statement (B), since it is has a trigonal pyramidal shape and isn't planar, but has equal bond angles.

(C) $\ce{AX3}$ must have at least 5 valence electrons.

Here, the valence electrons of the central atom is referred and not the total number of valence electrons in the molecule because, $\ce{AX3}$ has 3 bonds, thus, 6 electrons are involved in bonding at the very least. If 4 valence electrons are considered, that could equate to only 2 bonds, hence contradicting the existence of $\ce{AX3}$.
With that mentioned, consider $\ce{BH3}$, it has 3 valence electrons, less than the 5 stated in the question. Hence (C) is disproved.

With (A), (B), and (C) disproved, (D) is the correct option by elimination.

(D) $\ce{X}$ must be connected to the central atom via single or double bonds.